# Does it make any sense to acquire some sort of knowledge about manufacturing or engineering for computational design optimization?

Tags: computational-physics, computational-chemistry, education

Does it make any sense to acquire some sort of knowledge about manufacturing or engineering for computational design optimization?

I've viewed computational science to be an abstract science suggesting that things could be studied in isolation (or this could be a goal), but I wonder if there's value in understanding how physical tools are built as domain knowledge.

Comment: Please consider asking this question on dedicated stacks like workspace or academia

Answer (score 4):

Computation science lives by the grace of computing something. So if you learn about that something you will 1. make yourself more employable as an engineer, specializing in computational stuff, or 2. make yourself employable as a computational scientist who is able to talk to domain scientists.

So yes, by all means learn something about engineering disciplines; learn some numerical analysis, finite elements/differences/volumes, maybe something about semi-conductor modeling.

In fact, my HPC textbooks are written from this point of view. theartofhpc.com Volume 1 is more the why and wherefore of computations, while volumes 2/3/4 are about the specific how.

(I have no idea idea if the same story exists for manufacturing.)